# Webworker served from the local filesystem not working

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, firefox, local, web-worker

I am trying to make the [web worker example from MDN](https://github.com/mdn/simple-web-worker) to work when it is not served from a server but opened directly open from my local filesystem (via a via file:// URL)

The example works fine when served from Apache at http://localhost/1/simple-web-worker-gh-pages/index.html
but it doesn't when it is read locally at file:///var/www/html/1/simple-web-worker-gh-pages/index.html

The developer console shows that messages are posted but there is no answer from the worker. (I tried both Firefox and Chromium.)

How can I make it to work ?

(There's a similar question [failed to load script - Webworker (PDF.JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833332/failed-to-load-script-webworker-pdf-js) , but my problem is different, as I don't see a "Failed to load script" error.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid developing using file:/// - you'll waste time debugging, as not everything is supposed to work there.

In case of `Worker()` in Firefox, this was [supported a year ago](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/b3c1b37dddc2), but was apparently [disabled in Firefox 68](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/2ad059cc9e7835a1cf2a6f34be1c9e3f8eb7d7a4).

See [Firefox 68: local files now treated as cross-origin; is there a way to override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999411/firefox-68-local-files-now-treated-as-cross-origin-is-there-a-way-to-override) - if you set `privacy.file_unique_origin` to `false` in about:config, the example should work.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can afford the risk : https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-21/#CVE-2019-11730